# Break in debug mode in Xcode

Tags: python, debugging, xcode5

I am trying to set up the debugging mode in Xcode to run python so that it will stop at a breakpoint I set beforehand. I tried putting breakpoints in the python file and run as a project. However, it simply ran through the whole code and did not stop at the breakpoint set.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you trying to debug Python code in Xcode, or have you written LLDB Python scripts that you're trying to access in Xcode's debugger? I don't think Xcode supports the Python debugger. You'll have to use something besides Xcode to debug Python code. BBEdit and TextWrangler let you debug Python code. I can't help you if you're trying to access LLDB Python scripts.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to debug Python code in Xcode. So you are saying Xcode does not have debugging mode for Python. Aside from the two editors you have recommended, I suppose I can use "import pdb" to debug in command line, correct? But I suppose it will much more convenient in an editor that incorporates Python debugging mode, right?

Comment: I don't do much Python development, but I'd be shocked if you couldn't debug from the command line. I find it more convenient to use BBEdit or a Python IDE to debug Python code. But you might prefer the command line.